# Angular 12 Dependency injection in external library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, external

I need to inject a service into an external library for use it in a directive. this directive will be used in diferents apps and in diferents modules in each app. Each module will inject its own service.

Im creating an inyection token and a service interface in the module of the library, and importing its in the modules where are going to be used in the pricipal app.

then I provide the service using useExisting with this token, and in the directive use @Inject(INJECTION_TOKEN) in the constructor.

but i allways have this result when i load the componen where is used directive:
"NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DashboardModule)[InjectionToken service token -> InjectionToken service token"

In my library module

```
import { Directive } from './directives/directive.directive';

@NgModule({
   exports: [
      ...,
      Directive
   ],
   imports: [CommonModule,...],
   declarations: [
      ...,
       Directive
   ]
})
export class LibraryModule {
  }

export const SERVICE_ADAPTER: InjectionToken<ServiceAdapter> =
  new InjectionToken('service token');

export interface ServiceAdapter {
  a(): void
}
```

In my library Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Inject, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceAdapter, SERVICE_ADAPTER } from '../library.module';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class Directive {
  @Input() field: string = ''
  @Input() method: string = ''
  

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, @Inject(SERVICE_ADAPTER) protected service: ServiceAdapter) {}

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  keyup(event: any) {

        ...

  }


}
```

In the module where im going tu use it:

```
...
import { LibraryModule,SERVICE_ADAPTER } from 'Library...';

@NgModule({providers: [
      { provide: SERVICE_ADAPTER, useExisting: ProjectsService }
    ],
   declarations: [
     ...
   ],
   imports: [
      LibraryModule,
   ]
})
export class ProjectsModule {

}
```

Comment: When using useExisting, you need to make sure that the service you are trying to use has already been instantiated and provided in a parent module or component. The useExisting option essentially tells Angular to use an existing instance of the service, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: yes, the service has already  been instanciated in a parent component. By the way, the problem persists using useClass

Comment: It appears that the error message you are receiving is indicating that there is no existing instance of the service that has been provided, which is causing a NullInjectorError.
1) Use useClass instead of useExisting and import the service class in the module where you are trying to use it.
2) Provide the service in a parent module or component, so that it can be reused by the LibraryModule and the module where you are trying to use it.

Comment: iI've realized if I inject it in the constructor of the LibraryModule it injects ok, but i dont know how to use it in the directive

Comment: I think I understand your problem: You want a directives in a npm package, because you want to use it in different applications. You want to implement a abstract service that can interact with your directive. I make no sense to implement the service for each usage in your lib. That's the reason why you want to work with injection token.
So you can inject you individual implementation of the abstract service for each scenario. Am I right?

So you solution is "forRoot". I looked for an link for you:
https://medium.com/slackernoon/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7

Comment: @DanielMichelfelder not exactly. yes, the library will be in npm but the in a main app, this directive will be used in many lazo loaded modules. In each lazy loaded module, this directe have tu use a diferent service. That's why i use an injectionToken instanciated in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understand you right, the link above is the solution for you. If you want for each lazy loaded module your custom / individual instance of service_adapter "forRoot - Concept" is your solution.

You need a module for your directive in the library like:

```
export interface IDirectiveModuleConfig {
    serviceAdapterConfiguration?: Provider;
}


@NgModule()
export class YourDirectiveModule{
    public static forRoot(config: IDirectiveModuleConfig = {}): ModuleWithProviders<YourDirectiveModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: YourDirectiveModule,
            providers: [
                config.serviceAdapterConfiguration
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

In your lazy loaded module you can specify how your service will be provided

```
@NgModule(
{
  imports: [
    YourDirectiveModule.forRoot({
       provide: ServiceAdapter,
       useClass: CustomImplementationServiceAdapter
   })
  ]
}
)
export class LazyLoadedModule {
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I had to change the provide value because with ServiceAdapter it didnt work, but if I provide with a string or with an InjectionToken imported from directive´s module work fine. I finally used the injectionToken. I made an stackblitz with it working [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-gcujcj?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: You are welcome. I am glat to see that it works well. 